# Drop-down Function Depending on Targetting

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown box presented on W3CSchools that I wish to convert into less class-oriented CSS (rather than having a bunch of classes, I'll just select it through the primary parent).

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

(Effectively, I shouldn't have to have any classes here)

Here's the CSS:

```
 /* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Everything here works fine when converted over to being targetted merely by the `nav` element, apart from the functional stuff:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

I can try to convert these into,

```
nav > div:hover nav > div > div {
    display: block;
}
nav > div:hover mav > div > button {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

But nothing happens. I've even tried using the primary parent class of `.dropdown` and removing the beginning of `nav > div`, although it also returns nothing.

What is making the difference? I'm targeting exactly the same elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `nav > div:hover mav > div > button {` `mav` should be `nav` so maybe that caused you problems with testing.

Here is the relevant code without using classes:

```
/*selects the nav and then select the div that is the immediate child of the nav that is hovered. When that child div  is hovered it selects the first div and sets its display type to block*/ 
nav > div:hover > div:first-of-type{
    display: block;
}
nav > div:hover > button{
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```css
/* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}


nav > div:hover > div:first-of-type{
  display: block;
}
nav > div:hover > button{
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That was actually an unintentional typo; sigh. Do you know why my code (if we correct said typo) didn't work?

Comment: I think your problem is that you  went to the `nav` after you did the hover. I would continue going down the html tree. usually when you select elements you go from the parent and you isolate to the specific children. You need to continue the flow of the HTML document when you select elements to isolate them. Don't go back up. You went back up to the parent (`nav`)when you shouldn't of I think. like after `nav > div:hover ` you should continue to the next `div` not go back up to the `nav`

Comment: I always assumed when having one element affected by a psuedo of another (e.g. the `:hover`ing of it) you'd always begin the targetting of either target with the primary parent; in this case, the `nav`, like I do with the rest of the styling. http://pastebin.com/eAcGVdJu (this doesn't include aesthetic styling, but serves my point).